# Filtering and Sorting in Angular JS with List JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listjs

I have an array of objects of below structure, where CustList is an array of Customer records. I created 4 more variables to populate a filter dropdown.

```
//<app.js code>
$scope.CustList = [];
$scope.Customer = {
       "DataCenter":"", 
       "Geo":"",    
       "CustomerName":"",   
       "ESX":"",    
       "TenantKey":"",  
       "Env":"",    
       "Version":""
}
$scope.SaESX = _.uniq(response.data,'ESX').map(a => a.ESX);
$scope.SaEnv = _.uniq(response.data,'Env').map(a => a.Env);
$scope.SaGeo = _.uniq(response.data,'Geo').map(a => a.Geo);
$scope.SaDC = _.uniq(response.data,'DataCenter').map(a => a.DataCenter);
$scope.SaVersion = _.uniq(response.data,'Version').map(a => a.Version);
```

My HTML Code looks like this.

```
<div id='custByType' class='cardBody' scroll="auto">
    <b>Filters</b>
    <div class='filterBar'>
        <B>Geo:</B>
        <select class='selList' ng-model="Customer.Geo" ng-change='updateList()'>
            <option value="? string:?" selected></option>
            <option ng-repeat="geo in SaGeo" value="{{geo}}">{{geo}}</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>ESX:</b>
        <select class='selList' ng-model="Customer.ESX">
                <option value="? string:?" selected></option>
                <option ng-repeat="ESX in SaESX" value="{{ESX}}">{{ESX}}</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b>DataCenter:</b>
        <select class='selList' ng-model="Customer.DataCenter">
                <option value="? string:?" selected></option>
                <option ng-repeat="dc in SaDC" value="{{dc}}">{{dc}}</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <B>Version:</B>
        <select class='selList' ng-model="Customer.Version">
                <option value="? string:?" selected></option>
                <option ng-repeat="v in SaVersion" value="{{v}}">{{v}}</option>
        </select>
        <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' ng-click='resetFilter()'>Reset</button>
    </div>
        <div class='searchBar'>
            <span class='alignleft'>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' onClick='ShowAdd()'>Add All</button>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary'>Add Selected</button>
            </span>
            <span class='alignright'>
                <input class='ALLsearch inpField' style='width:100px;' id='searchSaaS' placeholder="Search"/>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' onClick='setPagination(custTypeList,10)'>10</button>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' onClick='setPagination(custTypeList,20)'>20</button>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' onClick='setPagination(custTypeList,50)'>50</button>
                <button class='btn btn-small btn-primary' onClick='setPagination(custTypeList,99999)'>All</button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <table class="newListTable">
        <thead><tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Tenant Key</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Geo</th>
            <th>DC</th>
            <th>Env</th>
            <th>Version</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody class="list" >
            <TR  ng-repeat="cust in CustList | filter:Customer | unique: 'TenantKey'"> <!--  -->
                <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
                <td class="tenantkey" ng-bind='cust.TenantKey'></TD>
                <td class="account" ng-bind='cust.CustomerName'></TD>
                <TD class="geo" ng-bind='cust.Geo'></TD>
                <TD class="env" ng-bind='cust.Env'></TD><td></td>
                <TD class="version" ng-bind='cust.Version'></TD><td></td>
            </TR>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class='pagination'></ul>
</div>
```

Im getting a beautiful out put where the table data is very nicely filtered using the vales from the drop-down.
[image: Screen Without List.js]
Now if I add List.js into this, thats when the problem starts. Two reasons why Im using List.js : (1) Gives me hassle free pagination. (2) Gives me hassle free search capability in the list!

```
var optionsSAAS = {
    valueNames:['tenantKey','account','geo','env','version'], 
    searchClass:'ALLsearch', 
    page: 10, 
    pagination:true
};
var custTypeList;

function loadList()
{
    custTypeList = new List('custByType', optionsSAAS);
    custTypeList.show(1,5);
}
```

[image: without Filter]

Problem : When I use the dropdown to filter, the list is getting filtered but its not rendering. In the below screen I filtered using a version, which has 3 records
[image: After filtering]

As you can see, the records are not rendered and the pagination is off as well. Im guessing Im missing something here, not sure what. If I click on Page 1 or anything, it resets the entire filtering and shows all records!

I have tried searching List.js with Angular Filtering but came up with custom Angular pagination/search, which is a lot of hassle in coding IMHO. Any thoughts?

Comment: Mixing AngularJS with third-party libraries that manipulate the DOM is asking for trouble. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Is there an Angular-safe library that can help me achieve the same functionality?